# Mongoose save does not work

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Just started with Node, Express and Mongoose.

Mongoose version: 4.1.3

Here is my model

```
  var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    bcrypt = require('bcrypt'),
    ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    Timestamp = global.requireLib('timestamp');


var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
  password: {type: String, required: true},
  first_name: {type: String},
  last_name: {type: String},
  username: {type: String, unique: true},
  role: {type: String, required: true, default: 'user'},
  created_at: {type: Number, required: true, default: Timestamp.now()},
  updated_at: {type: Number, required: true, default: Timestamp.now()}
});


UserSchema.methods.hashPassword = function () {
  salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(13);
  this.password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, salt);
}


UserSchema.methods.validate = function (password) {
  return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
}


var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema, 'users');


module.exports = User;
```

Here is 'controller' method:

```
   create: function (req, res) { 
      User.findOne({email: req.body.email}, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
          res.error('UnknownError');
        } else if (!user) {
          user = new User(req.body);
          user.hashPassword();
          user.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
              res.error('UnknownError');
            } else {
              res.success({id: user.id});
            }
          });
        } else {
          res.error('EmailExists');
        }
      });
    },
```

Request:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d '{"email": "user@example.com", "password": "123"}' http://localhost:3000/users
```

Routing works fine, if I add console.log() at the beginning of the create function I'll see it in console. If I do console.log(user.save) - I will se, that it is a function. But there in no any record an MongoDB. Update works fine, if I do update with upsert - it is ok.

6 hours left, still can't find an error.

Comment: Fyi, *Date.now* also works as default timestamp :)

Comment: @ThomasBormans thanks)

Comment: did you solve the problem in the end? i have the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
user.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.send(err);
    }
    else {
        console.log(user.id);
        res.success({id: user.id});
    }
});
```

Update the code and check what error are you getting in the console

Comment: There is no error! It seems to me that save is not executed at all! If I write console.log(1) before user.save - I'll see it, but none of console.log() (I placed them in save between all lines) in save will be in console.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to add **next()** to your `hashPassword` function like that?

```
UserSchema.methods.hashPassword = function () {
    salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(13);
    this.password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, salt);
    next();
}
```